# NMI: IOCK error

Tags: server, syslog

I am getting the following error messages in my syslog since upgrading to Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS:

> NMI: IOCK error (debug interrupt?) for reason 71 on CPU 0.
>
> NMI: IOCK error (debug interrupt?) for reason 61 on CPU 0.

Complete console output of the first error message: [IOCK error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN0kL.png)

```
$ uname -r 
4.15.0-36-generic
```

What do they mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic.  Solved the issue for me on HP DL380 Gen8s.  Found more info here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1771467

Answer (score 0):

I ran this problem yesterday and spent many hours solving this. I even downgraded my BIOS because I believe it is improbable my CPU is faulty. I gave up on solving this and went to disable Syslog broadcast message and etcetera instead to suppress the error message,  but it is not solving my problem, of course. Until I found some thread that mentions IRQ or something like that in BIOS. So I went to my Intel Celeron J1900 bios and set the IRQ setting from Continuous to Quiet. Surprisingly it solves my problem (or maybe, hides the problem.)